# No puedo instalar React

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo todas las condiciones para instalar react, pero aún así no pudo crear proyectos con esa tecnología.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que para tu versión de node la forma correcta de crear la app sería:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: ya lo intente de ese modo pero no funciono

Comment: has probado lo que indica @jose alfaro? También, en este post de aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977255/create-react-app-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command se resuelve un problema parecido añadiendo la ruta de npm al path de windows

Answer (score 1):

Después de intenta de todo, la solución a el problema fue hacer un cambio de versión de node js, para de este modo poder instalar React correctamente.